# How to scale a camera?

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to make a 3D scene where you can walk around the world, but my objects currently look way too small, and my camera's perspective is like from a Godzilla's. I tried to scale the camera on XYZ axis, but the view got distorted, also FOV doesn't help too.

Is there a solution to this? The only option I could think of now is to scale all of the objects instead. The problem is, there are over 100 objects, and I would have to change their parameters individually.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would be great to provide a live code example (code snippet, jsfiddle, codepen etc.), that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the scene

```
scene.scale.x = scene.scale.y = scene.scale.z = 10;
```

Or add objects to a group and scale that group:

```
const group = new THREE.Group();
// I guess that you're using some kind of loop for adding your objects?
group.add(objectA);
group.add(ObjectB);

// scale the group
group.scale.x = group.scale.y = group.scale.z = 10;

scene.add(group);
```